# JAVA Remove And Write Key And Value In YAML FILE

Tags: java, yaml

1- I Want To parse my yaml file with Java, but this method writes the key each time I execute I need to remove before writing to avoid duplicated entry please help

the content of my yaml file.yaml

```
dataPrerequis:
codeClient: 12345df
codeClient: 12345d
```

the methode:

```
public  static void getTestDumpWriter(String yamlFile,String key1,String 
value1) throws IOException { 
    Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
     data.put(key1, value1);
     DumperOptions options = new DumperOptions();
     options.setDefaultFlowStyle(DumperOptions.FlowStyle.BLOCK);
     options.setSplitLines(`enter code here`false);
     Yaml yaml = new Yaml(options);
     BufferedWriter writer = 
            new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(yamlFile, true));
     yaml.dump(data, writer); 
     }
```

Comment: `new FileWriter(yamlFile, true)` the `true` part means that it will append to your already existing file instead of overwriting it, remove this altogether or change it to false. If I understand correctly that's the issue you're having.

Comment: But I don't  want to remove all entry just the exit key, for example: if I have nameClient: test
codeClient: 12345d  the methode must replace codeClient that existe or remove it

Comment: plz any idea!!!

Comment: Read the existing yaml file. Replace the specific data you want to replace. Write the whole yaml file.

Comment: do you have code exemple?

Comment: The [SnakeYAML documentation](https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation) provides examples for reading and writing YAML that should be sufficient for your use-case.

Comment: @user3313418 If this works for you, you can answer your own question. Please don't put code in comments, nobody can read that.